# Implementing "Top Brand/Maker" in Solr

Tags: java, solr

My search box consists of two parts:

1. Autocomplete section implemented using Solr's suggest component.
2. The second part should display the "Top Brand".

For example if the user types "Laptop" in the search box, the autosuggest will display "Apple",  "Dell" and other words for example and the "Top Brand" section should display the brands (logos for example).

How to implement this "Top Brand" part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do have a separate Brand field?  If so you can facet on that field and sort by count.  Take a look at faceting on the wiki:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters